# Missing click stats

Tags: web-applications, facebook-like, facebook-insights

I've installed a comment plugin and like plugin on the article view page on a site, plus a like+send button on the header of the site that uses the http://site-domain.com/ url. In the insights panel I see impression for all of them. I see activities for the comments, I see activities for the send button in the header like+send plugin, but I don't see activities for any of the like buttons. I do see activities in the actual plugin on the page, I have liked a few things and it works, but no click shows up on insights.

Answer (score 0):

The clicks stat in insights refers to how many people clicked through to your site from the Like button activity that was shared on Facebook.

Comment: Thats what it shows on the right side: Impression on facebook(0) -> references from facebook (0). On the left side it shows: Imprssions of the like button (500) -> clicks on like button on web page(0)

Comment: Insights might be broken as I'm seeing unusual numbers too.